# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devexpress, vb.net-2010

VB.NET 2010 project, VS 2010, VSS (think it is 2008).

looking at other posts for this error, seems it is because of a change in a loop, enumeration, etc...  In my case, all I do is open the project, make any change, like re-sizing the form, save and close and when I reopen that form I get this error.  then I can undo checkout of the code and it opens fine.  Not even making a change to any code, just re-size the form.  ANY change I make, gets this error. The code is in production already and works fine, and I think it only happens on my pc.

Help!  Thank you in advance...

adding - actually it looks like it only happens in changes in the form, and the error is only on the form, not the code.  But it happens on any form.

Comment: Stab in the dark, sounds like an issue in some UserControl code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coworker figured it out for me.  It was an issue with DevExpress windows controls and Visual Studio.

Solution is here:
[How to enable visual inheritance for Developer Express controls.](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A2912.aspx)